# Why does some unicode characters change shape depending on which character is first used in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, fonts, character

I'm using Windows 11 and python 3.11.1. Some unicode characters change look depending on which character is used first in tkinter per font. The code below show the behavior:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

app = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(app, text="\u25b6 \u23EE \u270E", font=Font()).pack(side="top")
tk.Label(app, text="\u23EE \u25b6 \u270E", font=Font()).pack(side="top")

app.mainloop()
```

The output is the following:

[image]

Why does this happen? Is there a way to set the default look of characters in a font without adding a temporary character first?

Comment: It is not related to which character is used first.  It is caused by the option `font=Font()`.  Removing `font=Font()` from both `tk.Label(...)` will get correct output.

Comment: The reason i used `font=Font()` is just an example, this could be `font="Arial 10"` or anything else. The unicode character that is used first will set the style for all the other unicode characters in the same font. When no font is set, then it will use `TkDefaultFont`, and the same thing happens but can only be seen if the two `tk.Label(...)` lines are switched between runs.

Comment: No it doesn't: using `font="Arial 10"` (or the better `font=("Arial", 10)`) does exactly what you'd expect it to do, showing the same characters irrespective of ordering.

Comment: If you run the same code but change the font on the first to `("Arial", 10)` and the second to `("Arial", 11)`, then the symbols will differ. If you use `("Arial", 10)` twice, the second time it falls back on the same font and then the unicode symbol shape will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and eventually when trying unicode characters with Google Chrome I realized that this issue has nothing to do with tkinter or Python. It seems to be a larger problem with unicode characters in general. Here is what happens if you play around with the following unicode characters (⏮▶▶) in google chrome search bar.

[image: Problem with unicode characters]

Edit:

As Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans pointed out, this problem does not appear when using a font that supports all unicode characters that are used. For example GNU Unifont, http://unifoundry.com/unifont/, supports the unicode characters mentioned in the question and the shape for those characters are always the same when using that font.

The most probable reason this happens is depending on which unicode character is first used then different fallback fonts are used and therefore the shape may differ.

Comment: It has to do with "whatever is in charge of picking the font". If I run your code with an actual font specified (with support for the code points used), there is no emoticon substitution, irrespective of order.

Comment: Yeah that seems reasonable, did you find a font that had support for these symbols? If so I would like to test it out.

Comment: What do you mean with "these"? The blue ones, or the black ones?

Comment: The blue ones and the black ones use the same unicode characters but shown in tkinter vs google chrome, although the pen wasn't used in the latter. I tested out GNU Unifont and then this problem does not appear. As you mentioned, as long as the unicode char is supported by the selected font there is no problem, but if the current font does not support it, then depending on which font it falls back on, the shape may differ.

Comment: That depends entirely on the OS your script runs in, and the fonts that has installed, but you did mention Arial in your post's comments, and Arial is in fact one of the fonts that works just fine.

Comment: I created this code snippet: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#rqwz9s881cepd9gd4p6e5
for me this generates completely different symbols when using the same unicode characters and Arial.

Comment: Right, but what you're showing here is that the same font, for the same characters, _at different font sizes_ yields different results. Which is quite different from your post. Also, if you swap that third and fourth label, suddenly things render differently _again_, so at this point that is almost certainly a bug that you should report to the tk maintainers.

Comment: If you would switch the sizes around you would see that they do not matter, the reason this problem appears (my hypothesis) is because the first time a font is created they have not decided fallback fonts, but when they have been set once, they will continue having the same fallback font. The same appears to happen for several applications, e.g., VSCode when hovering a variable with these symbols, Google Chrome, Edge, Slack. Which is why I don't think this is a bug in tkinter.

Comment: I did switch the sizes. This is weird enough that if I found it, I'd report it as a bug. Even if you keep this question open (but then update it with this new code to show a concrete example of what's going wrong), this should get filed so that the only people can _really_ fix this, know that something needs fixing.

Comment: I posted this issue on: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101032

Comment: note that in that code, both arials are size 32, you probably want to make arial2 be size 33 as per the example you showed me above, and include a screenshot of what the result looks like.